# Oracle CONNECT BY recursive child to parent query, include ultimate parent that self references

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion, common-table-expression

In the following example

```
id parent_id
A  A
B  A
C  B

select id, parent_id
from table
start with id = 'A'
connect by nocycle parent_id = prior id
```

I get

```
A A
B A
C B
```

In my database I have millions of rows in the table and deep and wide hierarchies and I'm not interested in all children. I can derive the children I'm interested in. So I want to turn the query on its head and supply START WITH with the children ids. I then want to output the parent recursively until I get to the top. In my case the top is where the id and parent_id are equal. This is what I'm trying, but I can't get it to show the top level parent.

```
select id, parent_id
from table
START WITH id = 'C'
CONNECT BY nocycle id = PRIOR parent_id
```

This gives me

```
C B
B A
```

It's not outputting the A A. Is it possible to do this? What I'm hoping to do is not show the parent_id as a separate column in the output, but just show the name relating to the id. The hierarchy is then implied by the order.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got that result by using `WITH` clause.

```
WITH REC_TABLE ( ID, PARENT_ID)
AS
(
    --Start WITH 
    SELECT ID, PARENT_ID
    FROM table
    WHERE ID='C'

    UNION ALL
    --Recursive Block
    SELECT T.ID, T.PARENT_ID
    FROM table T 
    JOIN REC_TABLE R
    ON R.PARENT_ID=T.ID
    AND R.PARENT_ID!=R.ID   --NoCycle rule
)
SELECT *
FROM REC_TABLE;
```

And it seems to work that way too.

```
select id, parent_id
from T
START WITH id = 'C'
CONNECT BY id = PRIOR parent_id and parent_id!= prior id;
--                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
--                                      break cycles
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you very much. Clearly I don't understand the PRIOR expression well enough but this will help me to understand it better.

Comment: @Ftaveras I took the liberty to paste the entire working recursive query. +1 for that one