# determine no of layers of parent child relationship

Tags: sql, oracle, nested

Below is how data is structured in my table:
Notes:

P - indicates the parent

c - indicates the parent

A parent can have a parent ( having a child)
but a child can NOT have a child or either parent. Determine the layer/generations.

```
Column1,Column2
1-p,2-p:
2-p,3-p:
2-p,4-c:
3-p,5-c
```

how to read the above data:

- 1 has a child named 2;
- 2 has child 3 & 4;
- 3 has child 5.

So based on the above logic '1' has 3 layers.
How to write a query to determine no of layers in Oracle?

Comment: Maybe you could do it with a hierarchical query.

Comment: The short name for what you are looking for is "inheritance depth".  What does Column1 and Column2 actually mean?  Typically you will see single parent inherited data in a table with an ID and a ParentID column, but that doesnt line up with the data in your example unless the columns are ParentID, ID

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26439791/oracle-connect-by-recursive-child-to-parent-query-include-ultimate-parent-that  is an example of how to traverse this kind of table structure for ORACLE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a hierarchical query:

```sql
SELECT column1,
       MAX( depth ) AS max_depth
FROM   (
  SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT( column1 ) AS column1,
         LEVEL AS depth
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
  CONNECT BY
         PRIOR Column2 = Column1
)
GROUP BY
       column1;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Column1, Column2 ) AS
SELECT '1-p','2-p' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2-p','3-p' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2-p','4-c' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '3-p','5-c' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> COLUMN1 | MAX_DEPTH
> :------ | --------:
> 1-p     |         3
> 3-p     |         1
> 2-p     |         2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7bd84f753813339dbf2b98145260a2c6)*